# In a binary tree, print all nodes which are at a distance K from a given node

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given the root and a node in a binary tree along with an integer K. Write a method to print all the nodes which are K distance apart from the given node. This question was asked in an interview. Solution is direct if the given node is root node but here it can be any node in the tree. There is no parent pointer.

Given tree structure:

```
node {                            
 int data;  
 node *left,*right;  
};
```

Comment: Given a problem, show some effort.
What have you tried? (Google BFS)

Comment: If you are allowed to traverse up - definitely more applicable to think of it as a graph IMO. (Since one can call a binary tree a DAG)

Comment: There's no question here. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Along with `left` and `right` child nodes, store the `parent` node as well. Now starting from the given node, do a breadth first search and count the distance. If distance equals K, print the node and return.

Comment: There is no parent pointer. You can modify the tree structure.